# Press Button When This Number Appears - iMacros

Tags: java, c#, python, imacros

I happen to make a iMacros script for one of my web job but I think its not working pretty well as I thought.

I just want iMacros to Click/Press a particular button when a numbers appear in the web window. In the sense I just want the trade to "Sell At Market" price when it is in Profit percentage.
For example: I want imacros script to close the trade when reaches to 25% profit.

Please check this video to understand my concept.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfg1cm2vywzh8ve/iMacros_ScriptConcept.mp4?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

By the way this is what I got when I tried myself:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.binary.com/en/user/portfoliows.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:sell_at_market
```

Comment: Can you provide the html code for the number and the button. And also tell me at which number iMacros will click the button.

Comment: There is no html code for that. Just want to click the button when the number reached at "25%". Please check the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play the following macro in loop mode with a very big 'Max' value (e.g. 99999):

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(\(\+25\.\d\d%\))" EXTRACT=$1
SET butPos EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}' == '') ? '' : 1;")
TAG POS={{butPos}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:sell_at_market
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET E EVAL("('{{butPos}}' == '1') ? MacroError('\\n' + 'THE TRADE IS CLOSED!' + '\\n') : 'REPEATING';")
```